# Designing Architecture for MS Dynamics CRM 2011 with asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, dynamics-crm-2011

I required to create asp.net mvc application which will use MS Dynamics CRM 2011 as back-end.

I need guidance for designing architecture of this application.

Can anyone help me about how to design the layers of this application?

Comment: this is very very broad. too broad!

Answer (score 1):

Things I would suggest

- Use the CrmSvcUtil to generate early bound entities.
- Include the CRM OrganizationName somewhere in the MVC router.
- Create a single Lazy Loaded IOrganizationService once per Request (The IOrganizationService is not multi-thread safe)
- Decide if you want to use a System account with System Admin rights, or allow users to access CRM using their credentials.
- If you want it to look like CRM, you can download the css files from the SDK.

Comment: I know regarding use of CrmSvcUtil and I have also worked with that previously.  But this time I have to work with late bound entities.

Comment: Why would you want late bound?

Comment: @DevendraSolanki There is really no difference in the architecture if you're using late bound.  Just type your attribute names in correctly. ;)

Comment: I visited ddmvc4.codeplex.com, and thinking that can something like this possible for CRM and asp.net mvc. I know that CrmSvcUtil gives all CRM entities (models).  I just want to make maintenance easy.

Comment: @DevendraSolanki I would argue that maintenance is easier using the early bound entities.  They don't "Break" if you add a new field, or even if you remove one (as long as you don't attempt to update it or request it specifically in a select statement).  If you do happen to remove a field, regenerate your objects and now you've got compile time checking to see what will break.